# Is there any way to check if a pivot cache needs refreshing?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, vba

**Edit:**

Shai - thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't work for my purposes. I created some dummy data and pivot table and then changed some of the underlying data and your code still said the the cache was identical to the data. I think this is because you are looking for changes in the overall range, rather than changes within the range.

I've been playing around and using the documentation, especially the [PivotCache.SourceData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821224.aspx#) member that you use below and I don't think it's possible to do what I want to do. The best I've found is to create a new pivot cache from the original source data and to then somehow compare them (although this isn't possible using a direct equality:

```
Sub checkCache()

Dim ptTbl As PivotTable, pvtCache As PivotCache

Set ptTbl = Sheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, ptTbl.PivotCache.SourceData)

If pvtCache = ptTbl.PivotCache Then 'error on this line, cannot compare two pivot caches like this
    MsgBox "True"
Else
    MsgBox "False"
End If

End Sub
```

I'll leave this question open for a couple of days in case there are any more good ideas.

**Short version**

I need to highlight to users when the underlying data of the pivot table has changed and that they need to refresh the pivot cache. I can't just refresh the pivot table on every interaction due to performance issues.

At the moment, I am doing this with an `IF` formula that checks if the pivot table total still equals the sheet total, but this doesn't work for non-numeric data. Is there a better way?

**Long version**

I have several thousand rows of data that is categorised like the below (i.e. several categories and numbers that could change).

```
Name    Category 1  Category 2  Number       Number 2    Category 3...    etc.
Angela      A           X           123
Bob         A           Y           442
Bob         A           Y           566
Charlie     B           X           1445
Angela      A           X           5641231
Dave        B           Y           435
Dave        B           Y           45645
Charlie     B           X           567
```

My issue is that I want to highlight to the team (and myself) when the pivot table needs refreshing (i.e. when the source data differs from the pivot cache).

The workbook is large and takes a long time to calculate, so I don't want to refresh the pivot tables automatically every time the user interacts with the sheet. It is a standard company workbook and, although I've made some improvements to speed it up, I can't make large-scale changes.

I know I could build summary tables using `SUMIF` etc. that would update automatically, but I can't do that in this case.

At the moment, I am just combining an `IF` statement with some bright red conditional formatting that says

```
=IF(total from summing up workbook directly = pivot table total, "Pivot table OK", "Pivot table needs refreshing")
```

so the user will see a bright red cell telling them to refresh the pivot tables.

The issue I have is that this only works for the numeric data. If changes are made to the non-numeric data, the pivot table will need refreshing, but this approach won't work.

I could set up lots of different tables that count the occurrence of each label in each category and then check this against some pivot tables that count up from the pivot cache, but this will be lots of work. Can this be done another way in Excel or VBA?

Comment: An approach I've used in the past is to put the Table that holds the data for the PivotTable on another sheet, and then use vba to a) check if anyone made a change to that table and then b) update the pivot when that data sheet is deactivated. That way, users can make multiple changes to the source data, but it only gets updated when they switch back to the report sheet. Will that work for you?

Comment: @jeffreyweir That sounds like a good approach, I will look into it. Essentially I will just capture the event of clicking onto the report sheet and making the check then

Comment: @Jonathan did you read my answer below ? test my code ? any feedback ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes-  my apologies, I edited my question as I couldn't respond adequately in the comments - realise now that you don't get a notification when I do that. I like your code (and will probably edit some of it for other purposes), but it doesn't do exactly what I need. It only captures changes to the source data range, not the underlying data. Thanks anyway though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the current `PivotTable.PivotCache.SourceData` with the data resides in your sheet (that occupies the PivotTable).

If the `String` values are identical, you don't need to update the `PivotCache` and afterwards to refresh the `PivotTable`. If the values are not the same, it means the data structure has changed (more rows and columns were added / or removed), and you need to update the `PivotCache` and `Refresh` the `PivotTable`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckPivotCacheRefresh()

Dim PvtSht          As Worksheet
Dim DataSht         As Worksheet

Dim PTTbl           As PivotTable
Dim SrcData         As String
Dim LastRow         As Long
Dim LastCol         As Long

Set DataSht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name where your Pivot Data exists
Set PvtSht = Worksheets("Sheet2") ' modify "Sheet2" to your sheet's name where your Pivot Table exists

' find occupied Data Range for Pivot (starting from Cell "A1")
With DataSht
    LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastCol = .Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    SrcData = .Name & "!" & .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
End With

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit
On Error Resume Next
Set PTTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables("PivotTable1") ' set "PivotTable1" in your Pivot sheet

With PTTbl
    If .PivotCache.SourceData Like SrcData Then
        MsgBox "Pivot Cache Source Data and current Data are identical : " & SrcData
    Else
        MsgBox "Pivot Cache Source Data is : " & .PivotCache.SourceData & ", " & vbCr & _
                " while current Data is : " & SrcData
    End If

End With

End Sub
```